# What is the most idiomatic way to access the object an `std::exception_ptr` points to?

Tags: c++, exception, stl, monads

I'm using [tl-expected](https://github.com/TartanLlama/expected) to return from a function that might fail internally with an exception, using `std::exception_ptr` as the error type. That allows the caller to handle the exception in any way they want.

Rethrowing the exception is really convenient:

```cpp
auto resultValue = *calculation().or_else([](auto e){ std::rethrow_exception(e); });
```

Using the exception value is not as convenient. The `std::exception_ptr` class doesn't provide any direct access to the exception object (no `operator*`, no `operator->`). The only way to access the actual exception object is rethrowing the pointer then immediately catching the exception. This is the best way I could find:

```cpp
auto result = calculation();
if (!result) {
    auto err = "Error during calculation"s;

    try{ std::rethrow_exception(result.error()); }
    catch (std::exception& e) { err += ": "s + e.what(); }
    catch (...) {}

    std::cerr << err << "\n";
    return;
}

useResult(*result);

// ...
```

I think the biggest issue here is that the exception might be anything, so the standard library can't guarantee anything about the exception object, meaning the only reliable way to access it is indeed a try-catch block. But I'd like to know if there are any better options. What if I know before hand the exception object is an `std::exception`? Maybe I could use something other than `std::exception_ptr` for the result's error type?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: This is basically what [the cppreference.com example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr#Example) is doing.

Comment: Because any kind of object can be thrown as an exception, it's akin to `std::any`.  But (as you noted) without any mechanism to inspect the exception (other than `std::rethrow_exception`, as done in your example).  The approach you have in your example is the way to do it.  (Aside, you can also use this mechanism to propagate an exception across threads.)

Comment: The big problem is that the `std::exception` hierarchy relies on polymorphism which requires references or pointers to the base-class. So it's not really possible to store or pass exception objects by value as either the type will be wrong or it will cause slicing.